Initial bundle size over budget, not sure why
I can't get the bundle size of my app under max budget.
"budgets": [
  {
    "type": "initial",
    "maximumWarning": "500kb",
     "maximumError": "1mb"
   }
]

I know I could increase the 'maximumError', but I'd rather decrease the initial bundle size.

There doesn't seem to be anything eagerly loaded except the 'shell' component.
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ShellComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'welcome',
      },
      {
        path: 'welcome',
        title: 'Welcome',
        loadChildren: async () =>
          (await import('...')).WELCOME_ROUTES,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        canMatch: [
          inject(Store).select(selectUser)
            .pipe(map(user => !!user)),
        ],
        children: [
          {
            path: 'home',
            loadChildren: async () =>
              (await import('...')).HOME_ROUTES,
          },
          {
            path: 'books',
            loadChildren: async () =>
              (await import('...')).BOOKS_ROUTES,
          },
          {
            path: 'books/:bookId/reviews/:reviewId',
            loadComponent: async () =>
              (await import('...')).ReviewDetailComponent,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'welcome',
      },
    ],
  },
];

I use standalone coponents with module imports like so:
@Component({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...WelcomeMaterialModules,
    LoginComponent, // custom component
  ],
})
export class WelcomeComponent { ... }

@Component({
  ...
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...HomeMaterialModules,
    SearchComponent, // custom component
    SearchCardComponent, // custom component
    BookCardComponent, // custom component
    DividerComponent, // custom component
  ],
}) export class HomeComponent { ... }


import { MatCardModule } from "@angular/material/card";
export const HomeMaterialModules = [
  MatCardModule,
];

Some more examples of AngularMaterial modules import files:
export const WelcomeMaterialModules = [
  MatButtonModule,
  MatIconModule,
];

export const LoginMaterialModules = [
  MatInputModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule,
];

export const HomeMaterialModules = [
  MatCardModule,
];

I temporarily increased the 'maximumError' to 1.5MB, built (--prod) the app and ran the npx source-map-explorer over the dist folder.

The following is a snapshot of the browser 'network' tab. he chunks are not minified and add up to 6.6MB. After minification the app is 1.5MB, which is 0.5MB over the budget.


UPADE: I've just noticed that some Angular modules (e.g. '@angular_platform_browser', '@angular_material_dialog', '@angular_material_button') are downloaded multiple times. Is that supposed to be like that?


[ERROR] bundle initial exceeded maximum budget.


The components are not that huge and I'm not using large deps like e.g. momentjs...

Any ideas how I could decrease that initial bundle size?



Have you checked if the chucks are optimized (minified ?)

@MatthieuRiegler I ran the "npx...build --prod" over the project as described on the source-map-explorer site. So I assume the chunks are minified since that's ought to be the production build. Or am I missing something?

They seem reasonable. Without seeing the whole complexity of the app it's hard to tell. It could just be that the component's lazy chunks just are that big. 1) try additional build options e.g.:  "build": "ng build --prod --aot --vc --cc --dop --buildOptimizer --common-chunk" 2) Remove import CommonModule, and only import absolute minimum (manually import NgIf, NgFor etc).

Can you show us how you import Angular Material?

@JoosepParts Thanks for the tip. I've replaced all the CommonModule imports with its minimum necessary submodules and it's shaved off 0.5kb. It's 1.45MB, which is still  well over 1MB though. Regarding the build, I'm using the official '@angular-devkit/build-angular:application' executor. It's supposed to be as efficient as it gets. So there must be something else...

@ChristianVincenzoTraina - I've just updated my question, I added a few more examples of the imported material modules. Can you re-check pls?

some related to a .css?

@Eliseo what do you mean?
